# How are TP and RP rewards calculated?

Tags: robocraft

Ever since the "Walkers" update, they have removed repairs and changed the calculation of post-match rewards.
So, what is the new calculation of Robo Points (RP) and <s>Tech Points (TP)</s> rewards?

*There's usually a normal formula that then gets multiplied by a Tier modifier.*

A formula would be helpful.

Comment: There is an answer on the wikim idk how accurate it is: http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Robopoints and http://robocraft.gamepedia.com/Tech_Points#Tech_Points

Comment: Only the Tech Points information is accurate. The Robo Points information is a little out-of-date (referring to the ratios and multipliers from actions/events)

Comment: unless the makers make an effort to actively distribute this information, I don't think we will see up to date info calculated by users til it is very stable.
(Though given a few dozen RP pages, it shouldn't be too hard)

Answer (score -1):

It uses a damage system. The more damage you do. the higher amount of RP you get. I think TP has a difference with RP. so if you do 1000 damage, you'll get more RP.   ;)